# Check for new comments in a post instantaneously and add it into div without refreshing page

Tags: php, ajax, comments

I found a tutorial to add comments with the use of ajax [here](http://vortexdev.netii.net/article_12/Ajax_comments_system_with_jQuery_and_CodeIgniter)

Got it working but noticed that you need to refresh page to see comments of other people beside yourself, how can you check that if someone adds a comment you see the comments instantly without the need to refresh the page like what facebook does.

[image]

sample here someone posted on wall then when he adds comment you see changes instantly without refreshing the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript - [`setInterval`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp).
In function passed to `setInterval`, you check in backend whether there are any new comments. If so, you receive them and dynamically add to existing comments block.

**UPDATE:**

```
$.ajax(your_url_to_script, {
    type: 'post',
    data: {
        last: last_comment_time, // or just last comment, or Id doesn't matter
    },
    success: function(data)
    {
        if ( '' != data.content.trim() )
        {
            // code, that will add new comments to comments block
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: ok I get the setinterval but how do you check if there are new comments that is not yet included in the comments block

Comment: Read my answer carefully. It is all in there.

Comment: ok thanks deleted the comment sorry didn't see update till I refreshed the page